# Why am I not able to add a user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, database-user

I'm running command `grant all privileges on *.* to 'username'@localhost identified by 'strong password';`, but I get the  error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'strong password'' at line 1.

I can add a user separately and then assign it the privileges on the database, but I'd like to add the user and assign privileges in a single command. MySQL version:

```
| version                  | 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1       |
| version_comment          | (Ubuntu)                      |
| version_compile_machine  | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os       | Linux                         |
| version_compile_zlib     | 1.2.11                        |
```

Answer (score 4):

GRANT has no option for password anymore in mysql 8 see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'strong password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```